Reducing extreme probability predictions using a small sample
Let's say there are 2 racers in a race and I know for each racer a list of their times (lower number is better). Suppose the first racer has these times:
X1 = [6, 8, 10] 

And the second racer has these times:
X2 = [9, 11]

So, vector lengths don't have to be the same for all racers. What I want to do is calculate the probability of each racer winning. I would assume that each racer's time has the probability of happening equal to 1/N, where N is the number of samples for that racer.So, for this example the probability of first racer winning would be:
$$
1/3 * 2/2 + 1/3 * 2/2 + 1/3 *1/2 = 5/6
$$
The problem with this is that if we put X2 = [11, 12], then it calculates that the first one will always win, which is a bit of an extreme prediction because true racing times probably would follow some kind of bell curve. So I need basically a way that would transform extreme predictions into less extreme. So for example, transform
[1, 0] -> [0.9, 0.1]  

While something that was reasonably predicted should stay about the same
[0.7, 0.3] -> [0.7, 0.3] 

(or very similar to the original values)
Is there perhaps some function that could be useful to transform values like that?

So you have some prior information, look into bayes! Search this site
